# Fetch value from arraylist through linq in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, c#-4.0

I have an array list in this format given below in mongodb collection.

```
"Students": 
[
    null,
    {
        "name": "Rahul",
        "RegID": "A01"
    },
    {
        "name": "Raj",
        "RegID": "A012"
    }
]
```

I want to display name in string (Rahul,Raj).This is how I am trying.

```
Var Namelist  = students.Select(x =>x?.name)?.ToList();

String names = string.Join(",",Namelist);
```

But it also appends `(,Rahul,Raj)`.
I can do this by using loop but i want to write the exact linq query

Comment: The initial comma comes from the null entry I believe, so skip it using `students.Where(x => x != null).Select(x =>x?.name)?.ToList();`.  Does that work?  Your question lacks a [mcve] so I can't really test it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a filter to ignore empty entries. You can either do that in the source query:

```
var Namelist = students.Where(s => s != null).Select(x =>x.name).ToList();
```

(Note that I've removed a few null operators since you can assume that all of the values are not null)

Or when you join the strings:

```
String names = string.Join(",", Namelist.Where(s => s != null));
```

It's generally odd to have a null value in a list of related data, however, so might actually have a problem in the source data that you should fix.

Comment: ... and then go on to investigate why there are `null` entries to begin with and whether they shouldn't actually be there.

Comment: @Fildor Good point - added that to the answer